# Is Cassandra fully tested against OpenJDK or any non-Oracle free JRE

Tags: cassandra

Oracle’s new Licensing on Java is probably killing the programming language Java in long run. In short-term, what options of JRE do we have for running Cassandra without getting a big bill from Oracle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this is the wrong place to rant about a particular license or vendor. If you have specific questions regarding JDK compatibility, perhaps post directly to a Cassandra support forum (or check their repo?). But this really isn't where to ask about licensing and related billing.

Comment: Actually, nothing - not even Oracle - is killing Java. Oracle are just really poor at public relations or communicating properly. All of this just breaks down to "Do you want commercial support, which costs money? Use the Oracle JDK! Do you not want commecial support, and continue free of charge? Use OpenJDK!" They are actually byte-identical. It is just a difference of license.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Cassandra (3.11.3) supports [OpenJDK8](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites). So you have an alternative to Oracle's Java.